# How do I make a "input type text" go invisible with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="text" value="Text box"/>
<input type="button" onclick="toggle();"/>
```

How do I make the text box disappear and reappear with JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
function toggle() {
  var element=document.getElementById('element1');

  if ( element.style.display!='none' ) {
    element.style.display='none';
  } else {
    element.style.display='';
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="element1" type="text" value="Text box"/>
<input type="button" onclick="toggle();"/>
```

Comment: How did you put this code on stackoverflow's editor? It didn't let me put "input" tags on my responde, even beginning with a '>' char.

Comment: Thanks, and I don't know why, it didn't show your posts. That is why I "bumped". :\

Comment: @Gabriel - You need to mark up your code and click the code button in the editor.

Comment: Is there a difference out of interest between display='' and display='block' ?

Answer (score 2):

put this code on page:

```
<script>
function toogle(id) {
       if (document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden') {
            document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible'; 
       } else {
            document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden'
       }
}
</script>
```

Now, just give a "id" element to your input tag, and pass this 'id' to the call of the javascript function on your button. Something like:

```
<input id="element1" type="text" value="Text box"/>
<input type="button" onclick="toggle('element1');"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, and I don't know why, it didn't show your posts. That is why I "bumped". :\

Answer (score 1):

JQuery provides some nice built-in functionality for this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle() {
      $('#element1').toggle();
    }       
</script>
```